# Getting captcha plugin to work with register action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, captcha

I have the login portion working and the register page displays the captcha clearly, the .dll for [RecaptchaMVC5](https://recaptchamvc5.codeplex.com/documentation) says that AccountController does not contain a definition for verifyReCAPTCHA but it works with the login portion:

Examples:

Login thats working:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Verify the recaptcha response.
            ReCaptchaResponse response = await this.verifyReCAPTCHA(model, "key", true);
            if (response.Success)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Captcha Code!");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

My Register Mockup that throws errors on verifyReCAPTCHA:

```
       [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Verify the recaptcha response.
            ReCaptchaResponse response = await this.verifyReCAPTCHA(model, "key", true);
            if (response.Success)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

the error I get

Error   1   'ReCaptchaMVC5Test.Controllers.AccountController' does not contain a definition for 'verifyReCAPTCHA'

Comment: Solutions belong as answers, not edits to the original question. I've rolled back the edit since @majache has posted the same content (and you've accepted it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside Models folder >  AccountViewModels.cs There is

```
public class LoginViewModel : ReCaptchaViewModel
```

and

```
public class RegisterViewModel : <Place 'RecaptchaViewModel' Here>
```

That's how you assign the Captcha's view model to other models

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell by the source, there's an extension method you're unable to access. Looks like you need to add `using ReCaptcha.Mvc5;` to the top of your Controller's source file to gain access.

[`verifyReCAPTCHA(this Controller, ReCaptchaViewModel, String, Boolean)`](https://recaptchamvc5.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Extensions/ReCaptchaExtension.cs)

Also, make sure your `model` inherits from `ReCaptcha.Mvc5.Model.ReCaptchaViewModel` (as demonstrated in their [documentation](https://recaptchamvc5.codeplex.com/documentation)), that way you satisfy the method signature.

Comment: You would think but I am using Recaptcha.Mvc5;  infact login and register are both in the same accountcontroller file so it's weird it throws an error on Register(RegisterViewModel), I havn't tried it anywhere besides the login one actually

Comment: Not to argue semantics, but was the **C** capitalized (I assume a copy-paste error)?

Comment: Ah, just noticed. You're passing wrong model. You need to be supplying a `ReCaptchaViewModel` (and not the `RegisterViewModel` as passed into your action). Basically, you're trying to hit a signature that doesn't exist. (Does your `LoginViewModel` inherit from `ReCaptchaViewModel` but your `RegisterViewModel` does not?)

Comment: Ok that makes sense I will try that, I'm not sure how  LoginViewModel inherits from ReCaptchaViewModel

Comment: Well, you need to satisfy the signature I've referenced above. Only way to do that would be to supply an instance of `ReCaptchaViewModel`. (And, according to their [docs page](https://recaptchamvc5.codeplex.com/documentation), the LoginViewModel does inherit from `ReCaptchaViewModel`. So, if you followed the example you probably did so without knowing it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

assuming both these methods are on the AccountController, what is the method signature for verifyReCAPTCHA as the methods both send different models (LoginViewModel and RegisterViewModel) do both inherit from the correct base?

Comment: This is a great example of a comment (when further clarification is necessary in the post, it's not _technically_ an answer).

Comment: @BradChristie actually I agree with you, though I did add a further clarification, probably would be a better comment though

Comment: im not sure I follow, I think you're talking about this    Controller.verifyReCaptcha(ReCaptcha.Mvc5.Model.ReCaptchaViewModel model, string privatekey, [bool secure = false]

Comment: exactly, but as you have noticed from the other answer, you need to inherit from ReCaptchaViewModel